# How to move cursor to next textfield automatically after fill previous textfield in Swift Collectionview cells

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uitextfield, text-cursor

I am working on Swift application, In that I have OTP verification screen.
So, User can enters 6 digits otp in 6 textfields.
I have created collection view and in that cell I have added dynamically 6 cells.
I am able to entering text and validating.

But, My requirement is once first digit fills, automatically cursor should move to next one.

My code is below

```
    var insertedValues = [String]()
    private var arrayOfCells: [OtpCollectionViewCell] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let cellSize = CGSize(width:50 , height:50)
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.scrollDirection = .vertical //.horizontal
        layout.itemSize = cellSize
        layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 1, left: 1, bottom: 1, right: 1)
        layout.minimumLineSpacing = 1.0
        layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 1.0
        collectionView.setCollectionViewLayout(layout, animated: true)

     }

    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        
        return 6 // this may be dynamic count
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "OtpCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! OtpCollectionViewCell
        cell.otpTextField.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.otpTextField.delegate = self
        arrayOfCells += [cell]
        return cell
    }

    func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        
        if insertedValues.count > 0 {
            insertedValues.removeAll()
        }
        
        for i in 0..<arrayOfCells.count {
            if let textfieldText = arrayOfCells[i].otpTextField.text, textfieldText != "" {
                insertedValues.append(textfieldText)
                if insertedValues.count == 6 {
                    textField.resignFirstResponder()
                    self.performAPICall()
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        
        if range.location == 0 && string == " " { //restrict single and double space tap
            return false
        }
        let currentCharacterCount = textField.text?.count ?? 0
        if range.length + range.location > currentCharacterCount {
            return false
        }
        let newLength = currentCharacterCount + string.count - range.length
        return newLength <= 1
    }
```

Here is my screen looks like.

[image]
Any Suggestions?

Comment: You want to have 6 single-character entry fields, and automatically move to the next when a character (other than a space) is entered? If so, using a collection view is pretty heavy-handed... would you be open to another approach? If so, a horizontal stack view would make more sense, and would be rather easier to manage.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Mr.DonMag, but I have use collectionview cell as per my manager decision, So, I can't take individual textfields as my otp fields are dynamic in future they can set 10 digit and I have to support 10 digits individual fields without changing my code, that is the reason I used collectionview cell

Comment: Sometimes the **developer** needs to let the *manager* know there is a better way to do something. But, if you want to stick with a collection view... do you already have it coded so the layout is correct (variable number of cells, sized correctly, centered on the screen (I expect), etc)? If so, edit your post and include a minimal example of the collection view controller and your cell class, and I can show you how to jump from field to field.

Comment: I have added my screenshot how it looks like and my code also added here completely, Please check once

Comment: I have did with some logic using below code, Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the logic of moving cursor b/w textfields of OTP just map to your collectionview otp cells

```
     func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    if (textField.text?.count)! < 1 && string.count > 0 {
        
        if textField == textOne {
            textTwo.becomeFirstResponder()
        }
        
        if textField == textTwo {
            textThree.becomeFirstResponder()
        }
        
        if textField == textThree {
            textFour.becomeFirstResponder()
        }
        
        if textField == textFour {
            textFive.becomeFirstResponder()
        }
        
        if textField == textFive {
            textSix.becomeFirstResponder()
        }
        
        if textField == textSix {
            textSix.resignFirstResponder()
        }
        
        textField.text = string
        return false
        
    }
    
    else if (textField.text?.count)! >= 1 && string.count == 0 {
        
        if textField == textTwo {
            textOne.becomeFirstResponder()
        }
        
        if (textField == textThree) {
            textTwo.becomeFirstResponder()
        }
        
        if (textField == textFour) {
            textThree.becomeFirstResponder()
        }
        
        if (textField == textFive) {
            textFour.becomeFirstResponder()
        }
        
        if (textField == textSix) {
            textFive.becomeFirstResponder()
        }
        
        if (textField == textOne) {
            textOne.resignFirstResponder()
        }
        
        textField.text = string
        return false
        
    }
    
    else if (textField.text?.count)! >= 1 {
        textField.text = string
        return false
    }
    
    return true
    
}
```

Comment: thank you for the quick answer, I have few example code for multiple outlet of textifields, but I am looking for dynamic textfields like collectionview cells cursor moving, Thank you

Comment: I am accepting your answer and upvoted too

Answer (score 0):

I have followed above solution, But, there is much code if there are more otp textfields. So, I have optimised solution.

Because in future, We may increase OTP textfields count like 10, 12.
So, that is the purpose, I followed dynamic cells(Textfields) using collection view.

Here is my code

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        
        if (textField.text?.count)! < 1 && string.count > 0 { // for moving cursor to next field
            
            for i in 0..<arrayOfCells.count - 1 {
                if textField == arrayOfCells[i].otpTextField {
                    arrayOfCells[i+1].otpTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
                }
            }
            textField.text = string
            return false
            
        }
        else if (textField.text?.count)! >= 1 && string.count == 0 {
            
            for i in 0..<arrayOfCells.count - 1 {
                 
                if textField == arrayOfCells[i+1].otpTextField {
                    arrayOfCells[i].otpTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
                }
            }
            
            textField.text = string
            return false
        }
        
        else if (textField.text?.count)! >= 1 {
            textField.text = string
            return false
        }
}
```

This code is working as I expected!